# Why is the constructor of a generic class with a default-valued enum parameter not able to call protected methods of that class?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, mono

A simple test case:

```
using System;

public class Test<T>
{
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        A,
        B
    }
    public Test (TestEnum a = TestEnum.A)
    {
        DoSomething ();
    }

    protected void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

The compiler (this is using Mono in a Unity3D project, .NET4.0 target) gives an error on the call in `Test()` to `DoSomething()`. If I remove the default parameter on `TestEnum a`, it builds just fine. MonoDevelop wants to call the default parameter `TestEnum<>.A`, but that doesn't compile, neither does `TestEnum<T>.A` (obviously I wouldn't have expected these to work but using MonoDevelop's autocomplete that's what I get).

EDIT: the specific error is: `the name DoSomething doesn't exists in the current context`

Comment: This seems to compile fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: Try moving the definition of TestEnum outside of the class. Does that help? Having a nested type definition in an open generic class may be confusing the compiler.

Comment: Well, what does the error say?

Comment: Report Mono bugs here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/  Or fix it yourself :)

Comment: I wonder, does `Test<T>.TestEnum a = Test<T>.TestEnum.A` work?

Comment: `+1` for reporting the bug - In my experience, they do a great job following through and getting these things fixed; unlike some open source projects that just ignore bug reports for years.

Comment: Whoops: the error is `the name DoSomething doesn't exist in the current context`. Thanks for checking VS for me, I had a feeling this might be a compiler bug. I'll check out the link you posted Hans and submit this.

Comment: @ColeCampbell Nope I already tried that same problems

Comment: This compiles fine using regular Mono 2.10. Unity3D is using quite old version of Mono you will have to report the bug to Unity3D.

Comment: It probably has more to do with the fact that DoSomething comes after Test, than with the fact that DoSomething is `protected`. (So you could probably reorder them as a workaround.) However, it does look like a Mono compiler bug.

Comment: I wonder if it will work out fine when you make your `TestEnum` a standalone enum (not a nested one). In .NET each concrete substitution of the `<T>` parameter will produce unique class , so assume `Test<int>` and `Test<string>` are different types. Logically, `Test<int>+TestEnum` and `Test<string>+TestEnum` will be different enums, when nested. This could have confused the Mono compiler, so moving the enum out of the class could fix the issue. Moreover, the enum is all the same for any possible `Test<T>`, so no need to produce as many enums as `Test<T>` classes.

Answer (score 1):

As said so in the comments, this is a compiler bug.

It seems as your Mono development environment doesn't really like the protected keyword.

Use {public,private} for now.